# loop over forms to find if a field has a data variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop over all forms on a page, then see if they have a "missing-field" data variable. Once found, I then want to highlight that field.

Currently I have it working to detect if the data var exists, but now I can't quite get it right where I see if a field with that name exists. Pointers appreciated.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$( "form" ).each(function( index ) 
{
    if (undefined !== $( this ).attr('data-missing') && $( this ).attr('data-missing').length)
    {
        field_name = $( this ).attr('data-missing');

        if ($( this + " input:text[name="+field_name+"]").length)
        {
            alert('this part isnt working...');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To query any DOM element with a specific name in JQuery, you can just do this:

```
$('[name="field_name"]')
```

To query an element which is a child of another element, you can use this syntax:

```
$('parent > child')
```

So your code would be:

```
    ...

    field_name = $( this ).attr('data-missing');

    if ($( `${field_name} > input:text[name="${field_name}"]`).length)
    {
        alert('Value missing');
    }
```

`field_name` needs to be a selector of some sort. I don't know what the contents of `data_missing` are, but they'd need to be an id (like `#form1`) or something similar.

Comment: field name is just a name of a field that is missing data, the selector is the form itself which is where I can't get it to work using "this" like in the example code.

Comment: in your code, "this" is referring to the form itself (the "each" function is iterating over all forms in the dom, so a form is the scoped context for "this" in the callback).
in order to select one of the input elements (field) in the form, you need the proper selector, which is not "this" as that's the dom element Jquery returns.

The problem you're having is you're passing the entire element into the selector, which won't work. You need to find the selector you need from the element, and pass that in. Possible selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors